# Activity running in background after back pressed

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, onbackpressed

I'm working on an android app where I extensively used animations. The problem I'm facing is, if user accidentally or deliberately presses back button, the previous activity starts which is all right, but the activity which is not visible anymore continues to run in background. The Toasts are showing, medias are being played. Now the simple solution would be check for any running animations or running media by reference in onBackPressed() and stop accordingly. Is there any other way to completely kill that activity? because I don't keep reference for every animation in that activity. Nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: so do you want to that activity to stop working while it is in the background ?

Comment: yes. Even when I can't see the activity, it continues to run in background. Toasts are being shown, as well as sounds are being heard from that activity.

Comment: `onBackPressed()` is called when user presses BACK. Unless you have overridden it, the default behaviour calls `finish()` which should finish your `Activity`. If you have started additional threads or other background processing in your `Activity`, you will need to terminate those things yourself. Please show us some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps,

**Finish the activity from the stack**

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**You can Also try from Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".LoadingScreen" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

Comment: please share the Logcat

Comment: or try handling it from manifest as I mentioned in the answer .and comment the above code.

Comment: @Joy any progress buddy?

Comment: No. I have been continuously trying to solve it from then. But no luck :( If I still manage to stop the current playing media in onBackPressed(), the code continues to run in background and starts playing next media, Shows toasts. manifest trick didn't work. Should I share the logcat?

Comment: LogCat is too big to post in comment. what to do? I'm new here actually.

Answer (score 0):

Activities doesn't run in background they run in foreground.Without looking at code it is hard to say what could be causing this problem but probably It could be be the music service which you had started.

Comment: Actually its a pretty big code. But I'm trying to explain it a bit more. I have an array of MediaPlayer. In onBackPressed(), if I stop the currently playing media, the code continues to be executed in background, eventually resulting in playing next media as well as showing toasts. As the activity is not visible, obviously I cant see the animations. Well I's like to mention here, I haven't yet overridden onStop(). Should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

You should handle the animations and media playbacks according to the life cycle of the activity

Answer (score 0):

to kill activity manually you can use below method, where you want to kill activity

finish();

Let me know for any queries!

Comment: Didn't help....the previous activity started but invisible activity continues to be executed in background.